# Gridview doesn't appear when I try to fill by stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to fill a `GridView` using a stored procedure but it doesn't work as I don't see something wrong.

Here's the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }
}

private void LoadGrid()
{
    using (MathDBEntities1 db = new MathDBEntities1())
    {
        string name = Request.QueryString["qName"];
        string ID = (from tbl in db.checkQuizName(name) select tbl.QuizID).FirstOrDefault();
        GridView1.DataSource = db.QuestionsByQID(ID).ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Stored Procedure Code

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[QuestionsByQID]
@quizID nvarchar
as begin
select * from dbo.Question where [QuizID] = @quizID
end
```

Comment: Without the code of the stored procedure and your data it is nearly impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @Sefe I added the code of the procedure

Comment: Did you try to add a debugger break point and verify that the result of `db.QuestionsByQID(ID).ToList()` exists?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Yes it has value i also tested on SQL-Server

Comment: SOLVED! Always small mistakes, should have written in stored procedure @quizID nvarchar(max)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgPatscheider

Comment: Glad if I put you on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

As per OP's comment

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[QuestionsByQID]
@quizID nvarchar(max)
as begin
select * from dbo.Question where [QuizID] = @quizID
end
```